# Share a map across files C++

Tags: c++

I have a use case where I've to create a map of function pointers and use it across various files. I've written the code for the template in a header file, along with the code to fill the map. When I don't define map as static, I get an error saying multiple definitions of the map because I include this header into multiple cpp files. To avoid that, I created map as static. However, now the program fails with Seg Fault probably because map is not yet initialized when I started adding the functions. How can I solve this problem?

Header file -

```
#ifndef KEY_COMPARE__H
#define KEY_COMPARE__H

#include <map>

enum DataType {
    A,
    B,
    MaxType
};

static const int MAX_KEYS = 5;

typedef bool (*Comparator)(uint8*, uint8*);
static std::map<long, Comparator> ComparatorMap; // <--- This is the map

template<typename T, typename... Args>
long GetComparatorKey(T first, Args... args) {
    // Code to return a unique key based on first, args...
}

template <int N, DataType T, DataType... Ts>
struct Comparator {

    Comparator() {
        long comparatorKey = GetComparatorKey(T, Ts...);
        ComparatorMap[comparatorKey] = c1Func; // Seg fault here
    }

    static bool Compare(uint8 *rec1, uint8 *rec2){
        // Function to compare
    }

    static const size_t nKeys_ = Comparator<N+1, T, Ts...>::nKeys_ - 1;
    Comparator<N+1, A, T, Ts...> ci_;
    Comparator<N+1, B, T, Ts...> cs_;

    bool (*c1Func)(uint8*, uint8*) = Compare;
};

/// Other code for base cases and stop recursion

#endif // KEY_COMPARE__H
```

Edit:

I've also tried to create a struct with map as static member variable to avoid global variables. Even that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This if going to sound odd, but `KEY_COMPARE__H` is an illegal identifier. More on that  at [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a variable as `static` that means *internal [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage)*, which makes it kind of private to each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

I.e. each source file will have its own unique and distinct instance of the map.

To make the map global and shared between all translation units, just *declare* the map (using `extern` instead of `static`). And in a *single* source define the map (without `static` or `extern`).

And note that global variables are usually discouraged.

Comment: But I'm populating the map in the header file. If I define the map somewhere else, how can I make sure that's defined before it's populated? Won't I run into the same seg fault error again?

Comment: @Sashank You populate it in the *class*, but you do not *initialize* the map (beyond construction). And unless you create an instance of the `Comparator` class globally, then the map is guaranteed to have been constructed first (global variables will be constructed before the `main` function is called).

Comment: @Sashank However there are some other things with your code and question that  needs clarification. Like your use of multiple `Comparator` symbols for different types. And the fact that you get a seg-fault when you really should not get any, which indicate that you *do* construct `Comparator` objects before the map is constructed (smelling of [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)). I answered as good as I could with the information provided, which is clearly to little. Please create an [mcve] to show us!